# How to choose non-interruped numbers only?

Tags: r, selection

I have two vectors:

```
x<-c(0,1,0,2,3,0,1,1,0,2)
y<-c("00:01:00","00:02:00","00:03:00","00:04:00","00:05:00",
     "00:06:00","00:07:00","00:08:00","00:09:00","00:10:00")
```

I need to choose only those in `y`, where values of `x` is not interrupted by 0. As a result, I'd like to get a dataframe like this

```
y        x
00:04:00 2
00:05:00 3
00:07:00 1
00:08:00 1
```

We built a script like this, but with a big dataset it takes time. Is there a more elegant solution? And I wonder, why `df<-rbind(bbb,df)` returns inverted df?

```
aaa<-data.frame(y,x)
df<-NULL
for (i in 1:length(aaa$x)){
  bbb<-ifelse((aaa$x[i]*aaa$x[i+1])!=0, 
              aaa$x[i], 
              ifelse((aaa$x[i]*aaa$x[i-1])!=0, 
                     aaa$x[i], 
                     NA))
  df<-rbind(bbb,df)
}
df<-data.frame(rev(df))
aaa$x<-df$rev.df.
bbb<-na.omit(aaa)
bbb
```

I'm a newbie in R, so please, as much detail as you can :) Thank you!

Comment: +1 Great to see a reproducible example with a first question! Are you sure your required output is correct? Are you just wanting to subset those where `x` is not 0?

Comment: yes, this is correct question. i need to choose time when locomotor activity of caged animals appears first in a given day. and values, represented by 0,1,0 are often just accidental registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aaa <- data.frame(y,x)
rles <- rle(aaa$x == 0)
bbb <- aaa[rep(rles$values == FALSE & rles$lengths >= 2, rles$lengths),]
```

which gives

```
> bbb
         y x
4 00:04:00 2
5 00:05:00 3
7 00:07:00 1
8 00:08:00 1
```

The sub-question you had: `df<-rbind(bbb,df)` returns `df` reversed because you are adding the new row (`bbb`) before the rest (existing) rows; invert the order of the arguments and you won't need to reverse `df`.

Now to break down the answer, since it involves a lot of parts.  First, rephrasing your criteria, you want stretches of `aaa` that don't have 0's for at least 2 rows.  So the first criteria is finding the 0's

```
> aaa$x == 0
 [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Then you want to figure out the length of each of these stretches; `rle` does this.

```
> rle(aaa$x == 0)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:8] 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1
  values : logi [1:8] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
```

This means there was 1 `TRUE`, then 1 `FALSE`, then 1 `TRUE`, then 2 `FALSE`s, etc. This result is assigned to `rles`. The parts you want are where the value is `FALSE` (not 0), and the length of that run is 2 or more.

```
> rles$values == FALSE & rles$lengths >= 2
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

This needs to be expanded back out to the length of `aaa`, and `rep` will do that, using the `rles$lengths` to replicate the appropriate entries.

```
> rep(rles$values == FALSE & rles$lengths >= 2, rles$lengths)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

This gives a logical vector appropriate for indexing `aaa`

```
> aaa[rep(rles$values == FALSE & rles$lengths >= 2, rles$lengths),]
         y x
4 00:04:00 2
5 00:05:00 3
7 00:07:00 1
8 00:08:00 1
```

Comment: wow, so quick reply with nice script and perfect explanation! Thank you!!