# How to select just first elements in a row of the same values in R?

Tags: r, selection

i have two vectors

```
 x<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6)
 y<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l")
```

I'd like to choose only those in y, which coincide with the first element in a sequence of equal values in x
So, in my case the final solution should be like this:

```
    y x
 1  a 1
 4  d 2
 7  g 3
 9  i 4
 10 j 5
 12 l 6
```

We wrote a script and it works but need to add and delete additional rows (to use cbind later) which is mess for me.

```
aaa<-data.frame(y,x)
df<-NULL
for (i in 2:length(aaa$x)){   # you may see it stars from the second element because 
                               # of x[i-1]
   bbb<-ifelse((aaa$x[i]!= aaa$x[i-1]), aaa$x[i], NA)
     df<-rbind(df,bbb)
}
df
df<-rbind(1,df)
aaa$x<-df[,1]
bbb<-na.omit(aaa)
bbb
```

I have tried to apply rle() as it was recommended me earlier [How to choose non-interruped numbers only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790378/how-to-choose-non-interruped-numbers-only)
but failed in this case.

would love to hear your recommendation,

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
aaa <- data.frame(y, x)
aaa[!duplicated(aaa$x), ]

#    y x
# 1  a 1
# 4  d 2
# 7  g 3
# 9  i 4
# 10 j 5
# 12 l 6
```

Comment: Beat me by a second.  @AM note that the key to this is that `duplicated()` returns a vector of logicals which is FALSE for the first occurrence of a level and TRUE for every subsequent occurrence.

Comment: Thank you! it works perfect with the example, but i failed to adapt it to my real data. Guess, it's my fault, need more time to get the logic

Comment: @AM What was the problem with this code? I will try to improve it.

Comment: Dear Sven, my data represent as dataframe: two vectors here were just for a simple example. And when i apply your variant to dataframe, R returns warning massage "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length". just start with aaa<-data.frame(y,x) and then your code. Thank you.

Comment: fantastic! perfect! thumb up! i guess this variant will be the best solution for dataframes with many columns

Comment: dear Sven, i don't know how the system works here, but i think you should edit (or replace) your first code with new one and tick it as best solution for offered task.

Comment: @AM I modified my answer. You have to select the best answer. I can not do it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
justFirst <- function(x, y){
    stopifnot(length(x) > 1 && length(y) > 1 && length(x) == length(y))
    newX <- newY <- vector()
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
        if (i == 1){
            newX <- c(newX, x[i])
            newY <- c(newY, y[i])
        }
        else{
            if (x[i] != x[i-1]){
                newX <- c(newX, x[i])
                newY <- c(newY, y[i])
            }
        }
    }
    return(data.frame(newX, newY))
}

x<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6)
y<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l")

justFirst(x, y)
```

I'm putting this here as an alternative, in case there is a situation whereby x and y look like this (unordered and messy):

```
x<-c(1,1,1,2,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,4,4,4,4,3,2,3)
y<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t")
```

But, maybe there is still a better way of handling this situation ...